# Angular use of tokens when writing/reading from firebase rules-protected data

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, token

**The question:**
What is the model for using auth tokens to read/write from Firebase data?

**Long form question:** I have successfully logged-in to Firebase and I have a set of auth token data in response to that login.  I presume that when I do an http.get() or http.patch() to the Firebase document, I need to pass that token back.  But I haven't sorted out how to do this properly.

**Framework** ionic w/ angular

**Setup**
I have a Firebase data set established and I have set the access rules as follows:

```
{


  "rules": {
      "mission-cafe" : {
        ".read": "auth != null", 
        ".write": false
    },
      "issues" : {
        ".read": "auth != null", 
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

When I make an auth request to firebase, I get back a set of user data that looks like this:

```
Object
accessToken: "eyJhbI-long string-ww3w"

expirationTime: 1631656873062

refreshToken: "ACzBnC another long string dUJHK-"


[[Prototype]]: Object
```

So, now when I read/write from the Firebase Realtime Database, I  think I should pass back one of the tokens as part of the JSON payload in the html.get() or html.patch() statements.

```
const getString='https://freelance-xxxx-default-tdb.firebaseio.com/xxxxxx.json';
return this.http.get<{ [key: string]: MyData }>(getString).pipe(...)
```

**Key question 1:  What is the proper syntax for placing the token data that I got back from the original auth?**

As I read the documentation, I should evidently send back an &auth='long-token-string" in the http.get() or patch() statement... but I haven't been able to find documentation about which token to return and whether the keyword auth is in fact the right identifier for that string.

**Key Question 2:**  Apparently sending a uid is an option in lieu of an auth token.  In my application, I want to begin with anonymous login, so I won't have a uid at the time of the first data access.  Am I missing a concept?

Thanks for the help.

Paul

Comment: "When I make an auth request to firebase" Can you give more details on how you make this auth request. Via the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth)?

Comment: I'm using the Firebase SDK.  The call is a call like this: **this.fireAuth.signInAnonymously().then((data) => { ...**  And in **data** are the auth tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the Firebase ID token from the client, by following the method described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?authuser=0#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) in the doc, i.e. `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)`.

Then, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth?authuser=0#authenticate_with_an_id_token), you add it at the end of the url as a query string parameter:
`const getString = 'https://freelance-xxxx-default-tdb.firebaseio.com/xxxxxx.json?auth=' + idToken`

Since you don't share that much code, here is a generic JS example with the axios library:

```
 firebase     // use this.fireAuth.signInAnonymously() in your case
    .auth()
    .signInAnonymously()
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // We get the user from the userCredential,
      // but we could very well do firebase.auth().currentUser as well
      return userCredential.user.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true);
    })
    .then((idToken) => {
      return axios.get(
        'https://freelance-xxxx-default-tdb.firebaseio.com/xxxxxx.json?auth=' + idToken
      );
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // handle success
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
```

---

Side note: Is there any specific reason for not using the JS SDK for interacting with the RTDB? It is easier than using the REST API.

Comment: So good.  Your solution is helpful because it not only provides useful implementation, but is commented to teach the principle along the way.  Thanks.

As to why I used REST vs JS SDK.... well it's probably an artifact of starting with REST when I took my first ionic/angular course and then growing my knowledge organically from there.  It is certainly not a masterful architectural choice.  It's a consequence of learning-by-doing.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Glad I could help you. You may have a look at Angularfire https://github.com/angular/angularfire